# Creating registry DWORD entry with PowerShell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am trying to create registry entries for some time now.

Enviroment:

- Offline environment (No Domain)
- 1 Windows Server 2012 R2
- 200 Windows 7 clients

The following entry should be created on several computers:

```
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system]
"LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy"=dword:00000001
```

For this I would like to use the following script

```bsh
$Computers = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\Clients.txt"
$Path = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"
$Name = "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy"
$PropertyType = "DWord"
$Value = 1
$results = foreach ($computer in $Computers) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        try {
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name $Name -Value $Value -Type $PropertyType -ErrorAction 'Stop'
            $status = "Success"
        } catch {
            $status = "Failed"
        }
    } else {
        $status = "Unreachable"
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        'Computer' = $computer
        'Status'   = $status
    }
}
$results | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "./error.csv"
```

The script is executed, no error appears, but the entries were not created.
Where is my error?

Comment: You're testing whether the remote computer responds to ping, then create the registry value on the **local** computer. [stackoverflow://\[powershell\]+remote+registry](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+remote+registry)

Answer (score 0):

Always try a simple 'Get' first, and then progress to testing lines before trying your 'Set'...
So you first test locally on a system, before your foreach invoke, on single system:

```
`Get-ItemProperty HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy`
```

If you get a good response like this:

```
LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy : 0
PSPath                        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Curre
                                ntVersion\Policies\System
PSParentPath                  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Curre
                                ntVersion\Policies
PSChildName                   : System
PSDrive                       : HKLM
PSProvider                    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

Then you've got the right command to work with. Now change the 'Get' to a 'Set' and work out the values LOCALLY.
I think you are close, but missed something in your tests...
Do ONE  at a time, locally, first in PowerShell ISE. Then invoke-command to that same single system, then one by one add your tests...
- Patrick Burwell, 25 year Windows and Linux SysAdmin